# Golang replace previously opened file when new file is created

Tags: go

Ok so I am monitoring certain file and doing some tail -f analysis of that file. 
However another application has specific logic and it will create a new file on next date or even before.

I'm looking for a way to detect newly created file (host is linux machine) and then without restart of my current go service to start tailing newly created file.

Here is my current logic for tailing "current file":

```
func main(){

    currentTime := time.Now().Local()
    currentFileName := strings.Replace(currentTime.Format("2006-01-02"), "-","",2)
    newFileName := currentFileName + "_1111.log.txt"

    //using github.com/hpcloud/tail for tail
    t, err := tail.TailFile("/var/log/"+newFileName, tail.Config{Follow: true, ReOpen: true})
    for line := range t.Lines {
        //fmt.Println("Line is:", line.Text)

        //check do we have error inside new line
        if strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(line.Text), "mfc"){
            fmt.Println("MFC located: ", line.Text)

            //now send e-mail to all interested parties
            //sendEmail(line.Text)
        }

    }

    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Well current file instead 20161219_1111.log can be 20161219_2222.log or similar, and on next day it starts from 20161220_1111.log etc.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Try setting Poll=true as suggested by https://github.com/hpcloud/tail/issues/90

Comment: @HidekiAI how is that relevant, when I need to open an new file and close the old tail ?

Comment: So are you referring to 'tail -F' or 'tail -f'?

Comment: @HidekiAl 'tail -f'

Answer (score 3):

have a try with [github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify](https://godoc.org/github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify)

a simple example:

```
func newFileCheck() (newFilename chan string, err error) {
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        // do some log
        return
    }

    err = watcher.Watch("testDir")
    if err != nil {
        // do some log
        return
    }

    newFilename = make(chan string)

    // Process events
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case ev := <-watcher.Event:
                log.Println("event:", ev)
                newFilename <- ev.Name // Relative path to the file
            case err := <-watcher.Error:
                log.Println("error:", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    return
}

func yourApp() {

    newFilenameChan, err := newFileCheck()
    if err != nil {
        // err check
    }


    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case name := <-newFilenameChan:
                // close the old one and read new file
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

more details, see the doc

Comment: Don't use that fork. It specifically says that active development has moved to `github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify`

Comment: I did, but since this process in a loop, I'm not sure how to integrate my logic into it. Unfortunately there isnt enough doc in my opinion for this package.

Comment: use a channel to notify your application @Splendid

Comment: @simon_xia can u tell me then where to inject the channel within fsnotify function, I am not sure since if I get it correctly fsnotify is not closing it's own channel at all

Comment: @simon_xia thanks, but tail loop incorporated with "close the old one and read new file" will not work, since program will exit without tail loop.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the following as a hacked up example.

I'm not sure about the procedure to close a `tail.Tail` properly, assuming you call `Stop` or `StopAtEOF` and then `Cleanup`.

Also the concurrency aspects need to be refined. Goroutines need to be gracefully shut down.

Imports :

- github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify
- github.com/hpcloud/tail

Function to check for New Files :

```
func newFileCheck(dir string) (newFileAlert <-chan string, err error) {

    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = watcher.Add(dir)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    newFileAlertSender := make(chan string)
    newFileAlert = newFileAlertSender

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case ev.Op := <-watcher.Events:
                log.Println("Event : ", ev)
                if ev == fsnotify.Create {
                    newFileAlertSender <- ev.Name
                }
            case err := <-watcher.Errors:
                log.Println("Watcher Error : ", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    return
}
```

Function to Tail a file :

```
func tailFile(dir, newFileName string, cfg tail.Config, stop <-chan struct{}) {

    t, err := tail.TailFile(dir+newFileName, cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("TailFile failed - ", err)
    }

    for line := range t.Lines {

        if strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(line.Text), "mfc") {
            fmt.Println("MFC located: ", line.Text)
            //sendEmail(line.Text)
        }

        select {
        case <-stop:
            t.StopAtEOF()
        default:
        }

    }

    t.Cleanup()
}
```

Main :

```
func main() {

    dir := "/var/log/"

    currentTime := time.Now().Local()
    currentFileName := currentTime.Format("20060102")
    newFileName := currentFileName + "_1111.log.txt"

    newFileAlert, err := newFileCheck(dir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("File watching failed - ", err)
    }

    stop := make(chan struct{})

    cfg := tail.Config{Follow: true, ReOpen: true}

    go tailFile(dir, newFileName, cfg, stop)

    for fileName := range newFileAlert {
        stop <- struct{}{}
        go tailFile(dir, fileName, cfg, stop)
    }
}
```